# Is there a framewok / API I could use to export iPhone-SDK's ABRecordRef instances to vCard?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, vcf-vcard

I'm looking at source code from Funambol, but the dependencies are so huge, I'm rethinking of using them, not to mention the code is based on OC++. Can anyone help me out on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, afraid not.

You can either try to find a library / sample code in C/C++/ObjC that will generate a vCard from provided information, or attempt to roll your own.

You can find more information about vCard including the specs here; http://www.imc.org/pdi/